# Redis Function not found

Tags: redis, lua, redis-cluster

My setup is a 3 masters, 3 slaves Redis cluster, version 7.x.

I created a simple Lua based function as:

```
#!lua name=loggerLib
local function logMsg(keys, args)
    redis.log(redis.LOG_NOTICE, 'Hello!');
end
redis.register_function('logMsg', logMsg)
```

and loaded it as

`cat loggerLib.lua | redis-cli -c -p 7000 -x FUNCTION LOAD REPLACE`

However, when I execute it from the redis command prompt as
`127.0.0.1:7002> FCALL logMsg 1`

I see the error:
`(error) ERR Function not found`

What am I doing wrong here?

When I run it as

```
127.0.0.1:7000> FCALL logMsg 1 a
```

I see the error

```
-> Redirected to slot [15495] located at 127.0.0.1:7002
(error) ERR Function not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I see the error: (error) ERR Function not found

Because you call `FUNCTION LOAD` on one node (127.0.0.1:7000), while call `FCALL` on another node (127.0.0.1:7002). The function is only loaded on 127.0.0.1:7000, and the other node does't have the function loaded.

You need to call `FUNCTION LOAD` on every node in your Redis Cluster.

> I see the error
>
> -> Redirected to slot [15495] located at 127.0.0.1:7002
> (error) ERR Function not found

Because the key that your function tries to operate, located on node 127.0.0.1:7002, and your client is redirected to it, and again, it doesn't have the function loaded.

Comment: `127.0.0.1:7000> FCALL logMsg 1 a
-> Redirected to slot [15495] located at 127.0.0.1:7002
(nil)
`
I loaded the function on all the 3 masters. Why did the function call redirected to the 7002 port master node if the function is also available on the 7000 port master where I am attempting to execute?

Comment: posted another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78001723/print-call-issue-in-lua-based-function