# print call issue in Lua based function

Tags: redis, lua, redis-cluster

I have a Redis 7.x cluster with 3 master nodes running on ports 7000, 7001, 7002. Each master has 1 slave/replica.

I am trying to load and run this Lua based function:

```
#!lua name=printTestLib
local function printTest(keys, args)
    local time = redis.call('TIME');
    print("current timestamp in millis: " .. time)
end
redis.register_function('printTest', printTest)
```

When I run it as

`127.0.0.1:7000> fcall printTest 0`

I see the error:

`(error) ERR user_function:4: Script attempted to access nonexistent global variable 'print' script: printTest, on @user_function:4.`

What is the issue with the call to `print` statement?

Comment: Simply return it, like ```eval 'return(redis.call("TIME"))' 0```

Comment: ...or: ```eval 'return(("millis: %s"):format(redis.call("TIME")[2]))' 0```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running the Lua based function with `print()`, which doesn't exist since Redis Lua implementation is sandboxed.
You can simply fix this by replacing `print` with `redis.log` to log the message you're trying to call.

Comment: Yes, I know of the `redis.log()`. But I wanted the output messages to appear on the screen where I am calling the function through `FCALL` on the redis cli prompt.